# How to allow access cross origin requests ??? ( Angular, Rest, Spring )

Tags: spring, angular, rest

i need some help

i am developing an app using angular with restful web service using spring framework

after calling this method from RESTController

```
 @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
 @RequestMapping(value="/search",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public Page<Bien> chercher(
        @RequestParam(name="mc",defaultValue="") String mc,
        @RequestParam(name="size",defaultValue="0") int page,
        @RequestParam(name="page",defaultValue="5") int size) {
    return bienRepository.chercher("%"+mc+"%",new PageRequest(page,size));
}
```

using

```
 this.http.get('url:http://localhost:8080/searchmc=A').
 map(resp=>resp.json()).
 subscribe(data=>{this.pageBien=data;},err=>{console.log(err) } );
```

i got this problem

Failed to load url:http://localhost:8080/search?mc=A: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Any suggestion please!

Comment: Do you need url: at the beginning. From the error message it looks that is the problem. just use `http://....` without `url:`

Answer (score 1):

Your get request from the client seems incorrect.
The correct one should be :

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/search?mc=A').map(resp=>resp.json()).
subscribe(data=>{this.pageBien=data;},err=>{console.log(err) } );
```

What changed:

1. Drop "url" prefix in the get call
2. You include the request parameters in the url after the ?, so `http://localhost:8080/search?mc=A`  (Use & for every next request parameter, on example http://localhost:8080/search?mc=A&size=5)